# SharePoint 2010 and Localized Resource Files

Tags: localization

I am creating a bunch of masterpages and layouts which I need to provide localized text and labels for... is there an easy way to create and deploy localized resource files to use within my masterpages and layouts?

The below link seems like an easy enough solution, but if I can't use VS2010, what are my options?
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/provisioning-appglobalresources-sharepoint-2010/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+WaldekMastykarz+%28Waldek+Mastykarz%29

cheers.
ep3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VS2010 to do this. Just manually add the resource file element to your solution as described in the reference article. The resource file itself is an XML format and so can be manually edited if necessary, or using an XML editor with the schema. Then use something like WSPBuilder to create the solution package.

I know it is not as easy as using VS2010, but bear in mind that we used to craft all these solution and feature XML files manually (possibly with notepad) before VS2010 came along!